# Polynomial time reduction of 3-sat assignment to 3-sat decidability

Tags: computer-science

Say we have a poly time algorithm for determining whether a solution to 3-sat exists or not. Then find a poly time Algo for finding that solution

Comment: Now that's one super wide question if I've ever seen one.

Answer (score 0):

Repeat until you have no variables:

1. Pick any variable in the equation.
2. Look at `equation_false` and `equation_true`, the results of globally replacing the variable you picked with `True` and `False`.  At least one of them must be satisfiable. Use the fact that you already know how to solve 3Sat to determine which.
3. Set your variable to `True` or `False` depending on which of the equations is satisfiable.  (If they both are, just pick either.) Continue this algorithm with the satisfiable equation.

In Step 2, you know that one of them is satisfiable because you know that there *is* at least one solution to the original equation, and in that solution the variable is either set to `True` or `False`.